# To test mobile application on PC

Tags: android, android-emulator, mobile-application

I want to test mobile application on PC, is there way to do this? I have tried using Android emulator but nothing comes for me when I start the Emulator.

I have downloaded the Android SDK and then setup adp using Android command and when I launch emulator it does not show anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can happen a slow non-intel computer. the emulator may take hours to load. so what you want to do is work on the SDK Manager, and download all the components for API 10. then create a new emulator using TARGETING ONLY the API 10 forget about any NEWER APIs. when you set the emulator, if dont have an intel cpu, then DONT use the 'use GPU' setting and dont select to use the INTEL engine... try this... once you get it to run try API13, API15... or just get a NEW INTEL COMPUTER it will a lot faster